# Проблема кодировки при получении строки из subversion

Tags: кодировка, perl, svn

Продолжаю бороться с кодировкой при интеграции svn с bugzilla. В hook имею такую строку для получения комментария:

```
my $log = `$SVNLOOK log $repo -r $rev`;
```

При печати содержимого $log

```
print STDERR "лог ($Len): $log\n";
```

имею такую строку:

> `^@^@^@ (112): bug 1 ?\208?\183?\208?\176?\208?\191?\208?\184?\209?\129?\208?\176?\209?\130?\209?\140 ?\208?\184?\208?\183 svn`

Как все это побороть?

Comment: При копировании \' и \\ скушались.

    my $log = `$SVNLOOK log $repo -r $rev`;
и

    print STDERR "лог ($Len): $log\n";

Comment: Пр моему это вывод в UTF-8. А Вы в какой кодировке хотите ? 

Еще наверное, как вариант, переключить SVN на английский (скажем, export LANG=C перед скриптом, а потом можно назад).

Comment: Нет, содержимое `$log` уже содержит то, что напечатано, так как длина строки, которая отображается, 112. Исходная фраза: `"bug 1 Записать из SVN"`, что явно не 112 символов. Я читал, что SVN по умолчанию сообщения пишет в `UTF-8`, однако в консоли кодировка соответствовала `KOI8`. В файле `config` обнаружил, что в параметре `log-encoding` стоит `latin1`, сейчас проверю поведение системы с `UTF-8`.

Comment: изменение параметра ничего не дало. после перезагрузки тоже самое.

Comment: в переменной log у Вас текст в UTF-8 "bug 1 записать из svn" - первая 'з' маленькая (!). 

Перекодируйте его в кодировку, которую требует perl (наверное командой iconv). 

Кстати, обратите внимание, текст "лог" вообще пропал, это говорит о том, что русские буквы в скрипте набраны не в той кодировке, которую ожидает perl. Похоже он хочет UTF-8, а у Вас набито наверное в КОИ.

А может в этом и проблема ? Попробуйте набить "лог ($Len): $log\\n"; в UTF.

Comment: Если это было так просто то я бы сюда не писал. И в UTF8 сохранял файл и в KOI8-R все одно.
Включил даже прагмы: use open на IN и OUT, use utf8 - бесполезно.
Пришел к такому тесту: в консоле исполняю комманду

svnlook log /svndata/projects -r 156 > /var/svn/svn_bz/outinfo

Внутри файла в UTF8: нормальный текст

исполняю из файла:
`svnlook log /svndata/projects -r 156 > /var/svn/svn_bz/outinfo`

внутри:
bug 1 ?\208?\183?\208?\176?\208?\191?\208?\184?\209?\129?\208?\176?\209?\130?\209?\140 ?\208?\184?\208?\183 svn

Спецы! Помогите!

Answer (score 1):

Может попробовать делать это через модуль `SVN::Notify`, вроде пишут, что он дружит "UTF-8 if you have not specified --encoding." А где настраиваете, под Linux?

молодец, настройка svn мне тоже скоро понадобиться правда под Ubuntu

Comment: Да. Debian. Запарился уже с этим перлом.

Comment: Пытаюсь вставить сообщение в bugzillу с этим модулем. С кодировкой та же проблема. Почту отсылает, уже плюс, но в bugzillу пока вставить не получилось.

Comment: Воз и ныне там.
Вот письма, которые рассылает svnnotify.

    Revision: 74
    Author:   idmitriev
    Date:     2011-09-26 14:15:30 +0400 (Mon, 26 Sep 2011)
    Log Message:
    -----------
    bug 1 ?\208?\183?\208?\176?\208?\191?\208?\184?\209?\129?\209?\140 ?\208?\184?\208?\183 SVN
    
    Ticket Links:
    ------------
        http://bug.head.imsgroup.ru/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1
    
    Modified Paths:
    --------------
        RFPS/src/com/experian/rfps/Searcher.java

Comment: Спасение утопающих дело рук самих утопающих. Проблема заключалась в том что svn работает не скодировкой UTF-8. Добавление строки post-commit
export LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 решила данную проблему. спасибо всем кто отвечал на вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

А можно подробнее о решении проблемы, несколько недель ломаю голову, куда добавили строку?
Добавил в post-commit, "export LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8"

```
Debian-50-lenny-64-minimal:/var/svn/hooks# ./post-commit
svn: warning: cannot set LC_CTYPE locale
svn: warning: environment variable LANG is ru_RU.UTF-8
svn: warning: please check that your locale name is correct
svn: Can't convert string from native encoding to 'UTF-8':
svn: ?\208?\157?\208?\190?\208?\178?\209?\139?\208?\185 ?\209?\130?\208?\181?\208?\186?\209?\129?\209?\130?\208?\190?\208?\178?\209?\139?\208?\185 ?\208?\180?\208?\190?\208?\186?\209?\131?\208?\188?\208?\181?\208?\189?\209?\130.txt
```